# Set proper rights for sshfs mountpoint so it can be shared with samba

Tags: ssh, samba, gentoo, fstab, sshfs

I have a domain hoster that provides access via SSH.

My platforms are:

- Gentoo 2.6.36-r5
- Windows (XP/Vista/7)

I work on my Windows, I use Gentoo to do all the magic Windows can't do.

Therefore I use sshfs to mount the remote public directory for my domain to /mnt/mydomain.com. Authentication is done via keys, so lazy me don't have to type in my password every now and then.

Since I do my coding on Windows, and I don't want to upload/download the changed files all the time, I want to access this /mnt/mydomain.com via a samba share.

So I shared /mnt in samba, all mounts except mydomain.com is listed on my Windows Explorer.

My theories are:

1. *sshfs* does not set the mountpoint uid/gid to something that *samba* expects
2. *samba* does not know that it has to include the uid/gid that */mnt/mydomain.com* has been set.
3. All above is wrong, and I don't know.

Here are configs and output from console, need anything else just let me know. Also no errors or warnings that I take notice of being relevant to this issue, but I might be wrong.

```
gentoo ~ # ls -lah /mnt
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  root  4.0K Mar 26 16:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root  root  4.0K Mar 26  2011 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     0 Feb  1 16:12 .keep
drwxr-xr-x  1 root  root     0 Mar 18 12:09 buffer
drwxr-s--x  1 68591 68591 4.0K Feb 16 15:43 mydomain.com
drwx------  2 root  root  4.0K Feb  1 16:12 cdrom
drwx------  2 root  root  4.0K Feb  1 16:12 floppy
drwxr-xr-x  1 root  root     0 Sep  1  2009 services
drwxr-xr-x  1 root  root     0 Feb 10 15:08 www
```

*/etc/samba/smb.conf*

```
[mnt]
comment = Mount points
writable = yes
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
browsable = yes
path = /mnt
```

*/etc/fstab*

```
sshfs#myusername@mywebhotel.com:/home/to/pub/dir/ /mnt/mydomain.com/ fuse comment=sshfs,noauto,users,exec,uid=0,gid=0,allow_other,reconnect,follow_symlinks,transform_symlinks,idmap=none,SSHOPT=HostBasedAuthentication 0 0
```

For an easier read:

- myusername@mywebhotel.com
- /home/to/pub/dir/
- /mnt/mydomain.com/

*options:*

- comment=sshfs
- noauto
- users
- exec
- uid=0
- gid=0
- allow_other
- reconnect
- follow_symlinks
- transform_symlinks
- idmap=none
- SSHOPT=HostBasedAuthentication

Help!

Comment: IIRC, `HostbasedAuthentication` is not recommended to use (the user-based `PubkeyAuthentication` is preferred)

Comment: `SSHFS version 2.8`
`fuse: unknown option 'SSHOPT=HostBasedAuthentication'`

Answer (score 18):

`sshfs` is a FUSE-based filesystem, and the FUSE layer does not allow other users to access its mounts by default, for security purposes. You have `allow_other` in options, but it will be ignored until you also edit `/etc/fuse.conf` to include `user_allow_other`.

Comment: When exec'ing "ps aux", left column states root for both sshfs and smbd processes. I "parse" this as both runs with the same privileges. From the ls -lah output, you see the uid is not root, this uid is set by sshfs, but I can't set it, atleast not with changing uid/gid in options. I believe samba somehow think it has to exclude that specific directory with uid/gid 68591. (Trying to clear some confusion on my part.)

Comment: @CS01: The "master" smbd runs as root, but that is not true for connection handlers – if you log in over SMB as "jim", your smbd process also switches to the UID of "jim".

Comment: You also need to map the UID and/or GID to your desired user(s) via the options uid=<UID>,gid=<GID>.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. so to summarize, after tested on a recent version of Ubuntu: 1. update /etc/fuse.conf; 2. specify THREE sshfs command options (`-o allow_other -o uid=<UID> -o gid=<GID>`). It seems no need to restart `smbd` (but I am not sure since I restarted `smbd` anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you mount sshfs directly from Windows?
There are couple of free solution for that (see [here](http://dokan-dev.net/en/2011/01/12/dokan-sshfs-0-6-0-released/) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) for more info).

Comment: Wow, this tool is great!

Comment: They don't look very promising and are suspended, at least now, after 3 years :)
Do you have any stability experience with them?

Answer (score -1):

As your normal smb shares are working, i don't loose a word regarding the Samba config, because you can sahre sshfs mounts exactly like you share normal folders.
But mounting the SSH share via sshfs is special in comparison to local machine access only.

For mounting your share via fstab, you can put this line into
/etc/fstab
and mount the share ON REQUEST. It's more convenient than c&p the commandline command.

**Generic etc/fstab line:**

```
**<USERNAME>**@<SERVER>:<REMOTE_PATH> /MOUNT/POINT fuse.sshfs noauto,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,reconnect,port=22,uid=<UID>,gid=<GID> 0 0
```

**noauto:** you need to mount it via `mount /MOUNT/POINT`
        all other informations gets pulled from this line in /etc/fstab

**users:**  allows normal users to mount this mount entry

**reconnect:** reconnects/remounts the ahre after standby, etc

**uid=/gid=:** Maps the remote uid/gid to this local uid/gid

**Example:**

```
foo@example.org:/home/foo/music ~/foos_music fuse.sshfs noauto,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,reconnect,port=22,uid=foo,gid=users 0 0
```

All you need to know about sshfs mounting
[https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshfs]